# How to display username at login link in navbar after user has logged in

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want the login link in the navbar to change and display the username of the logged user, Please help how would I achieve that. Am not quite sure where to add logic statement in template

`views.py`

```
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
     user_form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
     if user_form.is_valid():
        username = user_form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = user_form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
            return redirect("loststuffapp:IndexView")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")
user_form = AuthenticationForm()
return render(request,
              "loststuffapp/login.html",
              {"user_form":user_form})
```

`login.html`

```
{% extends "loststuffapp/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
   <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{user_form.as_p}}
       <p><button class="btn" type="submit" >Login</button></p>
      <p>If you don't have an account, <a href="/register
<strong>register</strong></a> instead</p>
{% endblock %}
```

My navbar code

```
     <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li>

        <form action="{% url 'loststuffapp:IndexView' %}" method="get">
          <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search..." value="{{request.GET.q}}">
        </form>

      </li>
       {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
         {{user.username}}
       {% endif %}
      <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
```

[image: Home page image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the username of logged-in user in your template then you can do like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {{user.username}}
{% endif %}
```

If you want the login link disappeared after user is authenticated then you can do like this:

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
      <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

For better if the user is authenticated you give only link for logout and remove the other links

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
          {{user.username}}
          <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
{% else %}
 <li><a href="/login">Login/a></li>
 <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `request.` is not necessary here :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but am not sure where to add that logic, I have added my navbar and the login link. Please help am still new in this thing, Do I have to add it in "<li>login</li>" or outside

Comment: it depends upon you. You can write this logic wherever you want

Comment: I have seen it works, but I want it to replace the login while now it appear in different place

Comment: You want to remove login link if user is logged in

Comment: Yes! that is what I want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197657/discussion-between-kelvin-and-user11418935).